# Accessors e Mutators no Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Como faço pra executar meu próprio método no Accessors e Mutators do Laravel 5.3 ele funciona com os métodos do próprio PHP, mas se tento usar um método meu, ele dá erro.

já tentei assim:

```
public function getUsuTelefoneAttribute($value) {
    $generalInfo = new GeneralInfo();
    $this->attributes['usu_telefone'] = $generalInfo->masc_tel($value);
}
```

e tentei assim:

```
public function getUsuTelefoneAttribute($value, GeneralInfo $generalInfo) {
    $this->attributes['usu_telefone'] = $generalInfo->masc_tel($value);
}
```

mas ambos dão erro

Comment: O original é como?

Comment: O que queres fazer com esse método? O que queres que retorne a partir do telefone?

Comment: é uma mascara que quer na saída do resultado do usu_telefone??? é o primeiro forma que é a correta (vendo assim por cima) e como você chama? talvez está tendo essa confusão.

Comment: Eu tenho no banco de dados o telefone salvo assim: 1199999999 e quero que ele mostre assim (65) 999-9999 preciso aplicar esse filtro alí no getAttribute pra isso